# Does this sequence diverge $\frac{6^{3n}}{5^{4n}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I used the ratio test to get the problem in the following form:

$\left|\frac{6^{3n+1}}{5^{4n+1}}\right| \cdot \left|\frac{5^{4n}}{6^{3n}}\right| = \frac{6}{5} \gt 1 $ so the sequence diverges?

Comment: Is this a sequence or a series? You do not need the ratio test if it is a sequence.

Comment: @K.Jiang it is a sequence... sorry I'll update it

Comment: You're good... Your solution looks fine; you may also, on the other hand, take the limit of the sequence to infinity and discover that the sequence diverges.

Comment: Your method is wrong. Let $a_n = 6^{3n} / 5^{4n}$, then $a_{n+1}= 6^{3n+3}/5^{4n+4}$.

Comment: The ratio test would involve $$\left|\frac{6^{3(n+1)}}{5^{4(n+1)}}\right| \cdot \left|\frac{5^{4n}}{6^{3n}}\right|,$$ not the ratio you wrote, and this can be simplified into $$r=\frac{6^3}{5^4},$$ hence your question reduces to comparing $r$ to $1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac{6^{3n}}{5^{4n}} = \left(\frac{6^3}{5^4}\right)^n = \left(\frac{216}{625}\right)^n \rightarrow_n 0.$

Answer (score 1):

No!

We have: $\lim_{n \to \infty} a^n = \infty$ for a>1, $\lim_{n \to \infty} a^n = 1$ for a=1 and $\lim_{n \to \infty} a^n =0$ for $a \in (-1,1)$. (for a<-1 the limit doesn't exists).

In your case: $a=\frac{6^3}{5^4}=\frac{216}{625} \in (-1,1)$, so, the limit is $0$.